# iOS - UITableViewCell's image go ontop of table upon selection?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have 2 tables in one view. Table A lists a bunch of users. Table B lists a users objects. When a row is selected in Table A, Table B is reloaded with the objects that belong to that user.

So when a user selects a row in Table A, the image in the background of the cell changes to the highlighted version of the image.

Here is the normal version of the background image:[image: default image]

Here is the highlighted version of the background image: [image]

As you can see, the highlighted version has a small arrow on the right of it. This arrow is beyond the width of the table cell the table itself. When the row is selected, the image changes as it should, but the image is sized down to fit the whole image into the cell.

What I would like to happen is the image goes outside of the table, or on top of the table for that selected row.

One possible solution I thought was to center the table on the selected row and then overlay that image, but if the user was to try to scroll through the table, the image would need to move and that would be a big pain.

So what I would like to know is it is possible to extend the cell's size beyond the table one it is selected?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The following does not work, just in case anyone was going to try:

`[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width+20, cell.frame.size.height)];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a views clipsToBounds property to NO will allow the view to draw outside of its own frame.

In your UITableViewController subclass:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do what you normally do here, if anything then add...

    self.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
}
```

Doing this has a side effect where you will see full cells be created at the bottom or top of the tableview instead of them scrolling partially into view. Either put the table view into another view that has clipsToBounds set to YES, align the edges of the table view with the edges of the screen, or have views covering over the bottom and top (like a UIToolbar and UINavigationBar normally would).

To get the UITableViewCell's selectedBackgroundView to extend past the table view's frame create a subclass of UITableViewCell and override the layoutSubviews method.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YQGyZ"]];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CQXYh"]];

        self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.selectedBackgroundView.frame;
    frame.size.width += 13; // where 13 is the size of the arrow overhang from the same images
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = frame;

    // You can also change the location of the default labels (set their background colors to clear to see the background under them)
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, 148, 30);
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 30, 148, 30);
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend modifying the image resource of the unselected cell background such that it is the same width as the selected background, but just has a transparent rectangle on the side.